# Changing line spacing in collapsed dropdown menu (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Edited this to show code. Basically when my navbar is at full screen on a desktop, the dropdown menus work fine. But when the menu collapses on mobile, the main menu shows up fine, but it's dropdowns are all bunched up. I can't seem to change the line height for them.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mJyw.jpg)

Edited to show code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mobile-nav">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="VDiff" src="wp-content/themes/vdiff/images/logo/vdiff-small.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mobile-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Basics</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Trad</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Trad Basics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gear</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advanced Skills</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Big Wall</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Trad Basics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gear</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advanced Skills</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Alpine</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Trad Basics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gear</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advanced Skills</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.collapse a:link{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', sans-serif;
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
}

.navbar {
    height: 75px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;

}

.navbar-brand {
    padding-left: 50px;

}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: none;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: none;
    background: black;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
  border: none;
  background-color: black;
}
```

`

Comment: Show us You code...

Answer (score 0):

For first question you should use css media queries for making difference between desktop & mobile styles. for example for mobile screen use:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
    .collapse a {
         line-height: auto;
    }
}
```

And for none mobile use:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .collapse a {
        line-height: 45px;
    }
}
```

Or for example if you want your css to be shown up in tablet screens:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    // Some styles
}
```

See more details [Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries) 
For second question I'm not sure to understand what you mean. please describe more or make a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: This still didn't work unfortunately. I added the code above. I don't know what a jfiddle is, sorry! I'm just learning...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use padding instead of line heights for menu items spacing. But now just add line-height for nested a elements in dropdown menu like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #mobile-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
        line-height: 45px;
    }
}
```